# Content in Chrome alert box not being copied

Tags: javascript

It's boring to repeat the *inspect > applications > cookies* process every time. When I ran the code below, I saw that I couldn't copy the content. Can you help me?

```
alert(document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )shit_token=([^;]+)'))[2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `prompt` instead, as the text in the prompt's input will be automatically selected:

```
prompt('Token:', document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )shit_token=([^;]+)'))[2]);
```

Comment: @timosa you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark if it helps you :D